# Authentication by passport jwt and appending the req object with an object name 'user'

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

When using authentication by passport-jwt, does it always appends the req object with an object named "user"? Where does this name "user" come from?

```js
app.post('/profile', 
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
            res.send(req.user.profile);
    }
);
```

Does this code always append the `req` object with an object named `"user"`? 
From where is this name `"user"` coming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the definition of `passport.authenticate` from [passport source code line 12](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/42ff63c60a/lib/middleware/authenticate.js). So basically, `passport.authenticate` is a middleware it will do the data extraction and then bind data into `req.user`.

```
* Applies the `name`ed strategy (or strategies) to the incoming request, in
* order to authenticate the request.  If authentication is successful, the user
* will be logged in and populated at `req.user` and a session will be
* established by default.  If authentication fails, an unauthorized response
```